# Density and relative percentages

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A bag contains a mixture of copper and lead [BBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB_gun#History). The average density of the BBs is 9.80g/cm^3.

Assuming that the copper and lead are pure, how does one determine the relative amounts of each kind of BB?

Comment: Hi Austin, this is not so much chemistry as it is maths…

Answer (score 1):

Look up the densities of copper and lead from somewhere, and denote these by $\rho_c$ and $\rho_l$. Since we are interested in relative amount only, we can assume that the volume of BB's is altogether one unit, say $1 cm^3$, and split it into 2 parts: $x$ and $1-x$ (both in $cm^3$): $x$ is the volume of copper BB's, say.

So, considering the masses, denoting $\bar\rho$ the known average density:
$$x\cdot\rho_c +(1-x)\cdot\rho_l = 1\cdot\bar\rho$$